# Rewriting system of second order differential equation as system of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, vector-analysis, mathematical-modeling

Given a charged particle moving in an electromagnetic field. We have $N$ amount of point charges placed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ on the coordinates $p_i$. We also have a free particle moving in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is affected by the electromagnetic forces done by the points. 
The position of this particle with respect to time is given by the vector $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, which satisfies the system of differential equations:
$$\ddot{r}(t) = c\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{r-p_i}{||r-p_i||^3}$$
Where $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
We have to rewrite this system of differential equations as a first order one by introducing the help function $q(t) = \dot{r}(t)$. We can then create a vector $y(t) = (r,q)$ which satisfies the system of first order differential equations $\dot{y} = f(t,y)$. 
I managed to rewrite this system and got:
$$r= (x(t),y(t))\\
q = \dot{r}\\
\dot{q} = c\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{r-p_i}{||r-p_i||^3}\\
y = (r,q)\\
\dot{y} = (q,\dot{q})$$
But I can't find $q(t)$ which is required to find $\dot{y}$ (which I have to translate into python code later).
I tried doing $\frac{d\dot{q}}{dt} = c\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{r-p_i}{||r-p_i||^3}$ and integrating getting:
$$q(t) = \int \frac{(x(t),y(t))-(p_1,p_2)}{\left(\sqrt{(x-p_1)^2 +(y-p_2)^2} \right)^3} \ dt$$
But I don't have $(x(t),y(t))$ nor do I have any idea on how to integrate this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need an expression for $q(t)$, it is an unknown, just like $r(t)$. All you need is an initial condition for it. An ODE solver requires an expression for $\dot y$ in terms of $y$. You already have that

Comment: You mean $\dot{y} = f(t,y)$? But that's unknown too.

Comment: Can you use existing ODE solvers (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html#solving-initial-value-problems-for-ode-systems) or you have to write one by yourself?

Comment: I can, I'm meant to use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp() where I'm given some initial value of $y$ and $t$. The function that this method is supposed to take in (the $\dot{y}$) is what I'm supposed to code.

Comment: ODE solver accepts a function $f(t, y)$ that evaluates the right hand side of the ODE for a fixed moment of time $t$ and known immediate state $y$. The expression for $f$ you already wrote (it's on the right side)
$$
\dot r = q\\
\dot q = c \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{r - p_i}{\|r - p_i\|^3}
$$

Comment: I feel incredibly dumb for saying this, it feels like I'm simply not seeing something obvious. But isn't the $r$ an unknown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136558/discussion-between-uranix-and-alexander).